# subcaption: remove page number from lof

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, subcaption

I use the `caption` and `subcaption` package as shown in the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
A
\caption{test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
B
\caption{another test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can i remove the page numbers of the subfigures from the list of figures?
(subfigures are in my document always on the same page as the "main figure")

PS: tocloft seems not to be compatible with the caption/subcaption packages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This trick seems to work.

First of all, load the the `tocloft` package with the option `subfigure`, as if you were using the `subfigure` package.

```
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
```

Now, since in this case `tocloft` doesn't declare the counter `lofdepth`, we declare it explicitely and set it to 2:

```
\newcounter{lofdepth}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
```

At this point, we simply add the line

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}
```

to remove page numbers for subfigures.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\newcounter{lofdepth}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
A
\caption{test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
B
\caption{another test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]