# How do I remove page numbers from a list of figures with subcaption and tables?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, subcaption, tocloft, tabu

In [subcaption: remove page number from lof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132012/subcaption-remove-page-number-from-lof), someone asks how to remove page numbers from the list of figures when using subcaption.  This in itself works fine.

However, when I generate a list of tables with this configuration, the list of tables is completely blank.  What am I doing wrong?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{list=true}

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\newcounter{lofdepth}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\listoftables

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
A
\caption{test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
B
\caption{another test subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabu}{X | c | c | c | c }%
        Method & Mean Bin & Worst Bin & RMS Error & Dead Time \\ \hline%
        Delay line & 60~ps & 165~ps & 40~ps & 2.5~ns \\
        Type A (FSR) & 30~ps & 65~ps & 25~ps & 5~ns \\
        Type B (ISR) & -- & -- & 10~ps & 45~ns
    \end{tabu}%
\caption{A Table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution presented here should also work in your case: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129666/134144